# Nested Lists, dynamically adding a string to a list based on a date value

Tags: c#

I have a file with several data entries separated by a newline, and each entry has a date in it.
Knowing this date, I want to place these entries into a list based on equivalent days-- but I only care about the dates that are within 7 days from the current date.  I then have a top level list which contains these 7 lists, which again contain entries that contain that specific date.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<string>> week = new List<List<string>>(7);

        List<string> day = new List<string>();
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("TestCases.txt"); 
        StreamReader reader = fi.OpenText();
        string line;
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
        int currentday = current.DayOfYear;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] data = line.Split(',');
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(data[0]);
            int dateday = date.DayOfYear;
            int diff = dateday - currentday;
            if (diff < 0) diff += 365;
            if (diff >= 0 && diff < 7)
            {
                day.Add(line);
            }
            week.Add(day);
        }
        Display(week);
        Console.ReadKey();

     }
```

and my display function:

```
    static void Display(List<List<string>> list)
    {
        foreach (var sublist in list)
        {
            foreach (var value in sublist)
            {
                Console.Write(value);
                Console.Write('\n');
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

This will output all of the appropriate entries (Entries that occur within the next 7 days)
But it ends up adding all of the entries into one list and putting that same list 7 times in a row in my top-level list.

I have a rough idea of where to progress from here but I'm not too familiar with C# and I keep getting errors & google hasn't been helping me very much.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
List<List<string>> week = new List<List<string>>(7);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    week[i] = new List<string>();
```

Then:

```
if (diff >= 0 && diff < 7)
{
    week[diff].Add(line);
}
```

Haven't tested it yet, but it seems to be what you want. You should add date to the day of week you want, and what you are doing now is adding all dates to the same list, not recreating them and not grouping in any way.

Given the above, this could probably be solved better with some linq - better means a lot cleaner and readable.

Edit:

If you will put all dates into list, you can do something like this:

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>
{
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3),
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4),
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5),
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6),
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7),
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8)
};

var list = from date in dates
           where (DateTime.Now - date).Days < 7
           group date by date.Day;

foreach (var dateGroup in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date group: " + dateGroup.Key);
    foreach (var date in dateGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(date);
    }
}
```

Resulting in the same output. Not list inside list, but rather collection of groupings. Easier to get what code should do.

Comment: Very close, 
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                week.Add(new List<string>());
Ended up working.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the linq edit!
I have been learning more about it since you mentioned it, but thanks for your time and effort to give me an applicable example.  If I had 15 reputation I'd mark you as helpful :3

Comment: Glad I could help. Linq is very powerful tool so it's worth spending some time learning it. Have fun and good luck :)